# What is the byte order of the IP address specified in a callout's classifyFn in WFP?

Tags: kernel, ip-address, firewall, endianness, wfp

In a callout's classifyFn, one can use the following code to get the remote IP address:

```
inFixedValues->
incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS].value.uint32;
// IPv4
```

or

```
inFixedValues->
incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V6_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS].value.byteArray16; 
// IPv6
```

However, I can't find any documentation to specify the "byte order" of the IP address from MSDN, OSR, etc.

The following link is the same question as mine, but there was no answers.

http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=225090he

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't worked with IPv6 addresses, but [WFP gives you the IPv4 address in "host order"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfp/thread/a3cfd784-ca61-49e5-835a-f934a5348787) (little endian). If you need to change it to "network order" (big endian), you can call the [htonl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or if you're writing a kernel-mode driver you can use [RtlUlongByteSwap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: For IPv6, just print the byte buffer from 0 to 15.